# Spring Batch test case(s) ignore Spring profile(s)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm doing a PoC for a Spring Batch application. So far everything works fine, but I can't get the test(s) to pick up the `Datasource`, it always fails with:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 42 more
```

This is my `application.yml` file:

```
server:
  port: ${port:9080}
spring:
  http:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      enabled: true
      force: true
  output:
      ansi:
        enabled: detect
  profiles: # default, development, production
    active: default, development
---
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    sql-script-encoding: UTF-8
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:JavaSpringBootBatch;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL
    username: sa
    password:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
  profiles: development
---
server:
  port: ${port:80}
spring:
  datasource:
    initialize: false
    # ...
  profiles: production
```

...and my test class(es):

```
@Configuration
@Import(AppConfig.class) // This eventually "imports" the app's config
public class TestConfig {
  @Bean
  public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
    return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
  }
}
```

---

```
@ActiveProfiles("development")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
//@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
public class PlayerItemBatchTest {
  @Autowired
  private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

  @Test
  public void readProcessWriteBatchProcess() throws Exception {
    final JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
    Assertions.assertThat(jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob().getStatus()).isEqualTo(BatchStatus.COMPLETED);
  }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig { // Included with AppConfig
  private final DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  public BatchConfig(final DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  // ...
}
```

When I start my application I can clearly see that `datasource` has everything (all settings) I have in my `development` profile from the YAML. When I try to execute the test case(s) it just fails stating "it can't find the datasource".

Comment: Have you tried to add `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation for your test classes?

Comment: @AlexSaunin ...just did it, but nothing different; same error message that: `No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using @EnableConfigurationProperties
Try to create a .yml file in test/resources and create a TestConfig.java in test/src with @TestConfiguration annotations .

Comment: Nope, it didn't do it also. On the other hand, the YAML file in `main/resources` should be picked up if there is none `test/resources`. Since I'm using "profiles" this shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: I had the time to come back to this and you gave me a hint: using `@TestConfiguration` — I couldn't use it initially. I had `org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test` but not `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test`. I thought the first one was enough, but it looks like Spring needs the later to start the whole "testing infrastructure" (to name it somehow). I could accept your answer if you update it a little bit with that info.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do an explicit configuration of *org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer*
when using Spring Batch in conjunction with Spring Boot. This gives better control - you could find an example here: [Spring Batch with Spring Boot Integration testing](https://github.com/claboran/priceimporter/blob/master/src/main/java/de/laboranowitsch/priceimporter/config/H2Configuration.java)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a dependency configuration problem. You need a dependency on spring-jdbc for an embedded database to be auto-configured.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) is doc it can help you.

Comment: I have it since it's a transitive dependency of `spring-boot-starter-batch`.

Comment: have you tried with exclude transitive dependency from spring-boot-starter-batch and then add the dependency of it?

Comment: Yes...but it didn't do anything different also. Keep in mind this works when I normally start the application, so the issue is in the test(s).